# Xamarin storyboard vs. Simulator issue - Tableviewcell autolayout and contraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

My storyboard is showing the correct layout however I receive a different result in the simulator. I can't determine the issue.
Code and images below:

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oslhX.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndhrc.png)

```
        xGrid.RowHeight = 99;
        xGrid.Source = new IATableSource(items, this);       
        xGrid.ReloadData();
        xGrid.LayoutIfNeeded();

 public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        ItemAddCell cell = (ItemAddCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier, indexPath);
        Item item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];
        cell.UpdateCell(item.Title,item.Description);
        cell.LayoutIfNeeded();

        return cell;

    }
```

Comment: Add the same Top space constraint to your switch.

Comment: Added. Label still shows correct in storyboard but doesn't wrap and bleeds off the screen in Simulator